Finding example of non linear Bi-skew Jordan derivation which is not additive derivation
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be $\ast$-algebra over a field $\mathbb{F}$. By a nonlinear bi-skew Jordan derivation, I mean $d(A\diamond B)=d(AB^\ast+BA^\ast)=d(A)B^\ast+Ad(B)^\ast+d(B)A^\ast+Bd(A)^\ast$ for all $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$. I am having hard time to find an example of such a map which satisfies this property but either not additive($d(A+B)=d(A)+d(B)$) or not follow Leibnitz rule($d(AB)=d(A)B+Ad(B)$). It is already proved that Bi-skew Jordan derivation is additive on prime $\ast$ algebra. It means such example can only be found on non prime $\ast$ algebras. Any hint is very valuable for me. Thanks
